# Which STL reference book would recommend?

Tags: c++, stl

I am considering to put one of the following as a reference on my desk (as I am sick and tired to google every time I have a STL question):

- [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260)
- [STL Tutorial and Reference Guide: C++ Programming with the Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379236)
- [Generic Programming and the STL: Using and Extending the C++ Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309564)
- [Using the STL: The C++ Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387988572) (why is this guy so overpriced -- $110?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of Scott Meyers' books are excellent, including ["Effective STL"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).  It's not a handbook or a tutorial, but worth having.

Comment: I have this one, but it cannot be used as a general reference.

Comment: While this is not a reference book, after using it the SGI Documentation is the only reference you need.

Answer (score 3):

I read *The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference*, and found it extremely useful. I was already a "very advanced" C++ programmer before I read it, and I didn't feel like I was wasting my time reading through lots of beginner material.

Answer (score 1):

I only have Josuttis's book *The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference*, so I can't provide a comparison, but that book is very good, so I don't think you'd go wrong if you picked that. Also note that Josuttis covers the whole standard library whereas the other books seem to be only about the STL; that was the reason I got that book because I also wanted to understand things like I/O, which is not part of the STL.

Answer (score 1):

The Josuttis book has been very useful to me, but most of the time I head straight for the companion [web site](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/idx.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first - Josuttis' The C++ Standard Lib: Tutorial and Reference for the depth.  I like to keep [O'Reilly's STL Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005563) around for quick lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a reference reference, like what are the functions etc. you can try the SGI STL reference documentation. Granted, it's not a book, and it is a bit dated, but it's fairly well done, and has good documentation of concepts etc.

Just my two cents!

[SGI STL Documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)